# struct problems with malloc

Tags: c, struct

Today I want to try something out what I learned in struct but unfornuate it didnt compiled ...

this here is my code

```
struct Addresse
{
char street[20];
};


struct Person
{
char name[20];
int age;
char job[20];
struct Addresse mainstreet;
};

void callbyReference(struct Person* p)
{ 
printf("%s,%d,%s,%s\n",p->name,p->age,p->job,p->mainstreet.street );
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
struct Person *person;
person = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));

strcpy(person.name, "Max");
person.age = 14;
strcpy(person.job,"firefighter");
strcpy(person.mainstreet.street,"Fressnitz");

callbyReference(&person);
free(person)

return 0;
}
```

When i compiled it there is this error warning: request for member job in something not a structure or union.

Comment: `person` is a pointer to `struct`, so you can't access it's members via `.`. Use `->`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `strcpy(person->name, "Max")`, but `strcpy(person->mainstreet.street,"Fressnitz")`

Comment: Thanks! I correct it and it works now!

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via single blank line.

Comment: when posting a question about a compile time problem, as this question is, post the full code, so we don't have to guess (nor request clarification) as to which header files were included.

Answer (score 3):

There are two mistakes in your code.

After you allocate the `struct Person` instance with `malloc()` and assign it to your `person` variable, you are accessing its members using the `.` operator, but since `person` is a pointer you need to use the `->` operator instead:

```
struct Person *person;
... 
strcpy(person->name, "Max");
person->age = 14;
strcpy(person->job,"firefighter");
strcpy(person->mainstreet.street,"Fressnitz");
```

Once you fix that, you will get a new error, because `callbyReference()` expects a `struct Person *` pointer, ie a single pointer directly to an actual `Person` instance, but you are passing it a `struct Person **` pointer instead, ie a pointer to a pointer to a `Person` instance:

```
struct Person *person;
... 
callbyReference(&person);
```

So, get rid of the `&` address operator when passing your `person` variable to `callbyReference()`, as it is already a suitable pointer as-is:

```
callbyReference(person);
```

Your code would be using the `.` and `&` operators correctly if you had allocated `person` on the stack instead of via `malloc()`, eg:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct Person person;

    strcpy(person.name, "Max");
    person.age = 14;
    strcpy(person.job,"firefighter");
    strcpy(person.mainstreet.street,"Fressnitz");

    callbyReference(&person);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Always forgot this -> ... and yeah the callbyreference was a error too!

Comment: shouldnt it be strcpy(&(person->name), "Max") ?

Comment: @Nevado: No. If you pass just the name of a fixed array, it decays into a pointer to the array's first element. `strcpy(&(person->name[0]), ...)` and `strcpy(person->name, ...)` are identical. On the other hand, `&(person->name)` is not a `char*` pointer like the other two are, it is a pointer to an array, which is a slightly different type of pointer, and not suitable in this case.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sorry, I didn't notice that in your code person was not a pointer as in the original.

Comment: @Nevado `person` *IS* a pointer in my answer, that is what you commented on. I also added a non-pointer example after you posted your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To access the elements of the structure person, you should use `->`, not the `.` operator. 
Just as you did on line 21; `p->mainstreet.street`, this is how you should use your arrow selection operator(`->`) and the dot(`.`). In this case, the dot operator was used to access the members of another structure, namely `Address` while the arrow selection operator was used to access the members of its outer structure.

Here's the code that works, as a modification to your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Addresse
{
   char street[20];
};


struct Person
{
   char name[20];
   int age;
   char job[20];
   struct Addresse mainstreet;
};

void callbyReference(struct Person* p)
{ 
   printf("%s,%d,%s,%s\n",p->name,p->age,p->job,p->mainstreet.street );
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   struct Person *person;
   person = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));

   strcpy(person->name, "Max");
   person->age = 14;
   strcpy(person->job,"firefighter");
   strcpy(person->mainstreet.street,"Fressnitz");

   callbyReference(person);
   free(person);

   return 0;
}
```